# Make function always asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

can someone please help me to get my head around this code ? I can't quite determine by myself what code will be executed first in this case :/ Apparently this ensures that it will always print 1 to the console, but i don't get why is that. Also the line with "orig_fn.bind.apply..." is quite confusing for me :/

```
function asyncify(fn) {
    var orig_fn = fn,
        intv = setTimeout( function(){
            intv = null;
            if (fn) fn();
        }, 0 )
    ;

    fn = null;

    return function() {
        // firing too quickly, before `intv` timer has fired to
        // indicate async turn has passed?
        if (intv) {
            fn = orig_fn.bind.apply(
                orig_fn,
                // add the wrapper's `this` to the `bind(..)`
                // call parameters, as well as currying any
                // passed in parameters
                [this].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) )
            );
        }
        // already async
        else {
            // invoke original function
            orig_fn.apply( this, arguments );
        }
    };
}

function result(data) {
    console.log( a );
}

var a = 0;

ajax( "..pre-cached-url..", asyncify( result ) );
a++;
```

Comment: I would start by reading the documentation on [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), etc.

Comment: Also, just get a debugger on it and step through the code. That's the easiest way of seeing "what code will be executed first".

Comment: debugger will probably fail miserably at trying to investigate async calls. It can be done, but requires certain mastery at using chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand what your `asyncify()` function does.

First, notice that it gets called immediately, to provide its result as a second argument of your `ajax()` call. It returns an anonymous function.

Now, depending on when that anonymous function is called, one of two things happen:

1) if it's called immediately, the `setTimeout` didn't trigger yet, therefore it gets the arguments it was called with, and wraps them together with the original function `asyncify()` was called with, which is `result` in your case. The wrapping is done using `bind()`. Then it exits, letting timeout handle the actual call.

2) if it's not called immediately, when it is called, the timeout has lapsed already, so it can call the original function with its new parameters right away. This is done using `apply()`.